# Using php-mqtt to ping a device

Tags: php, mqtt, mosquitto, phpmqtt

so I'm trying to publish a "ping" request to a public mqtt server from my php website and wait for the device to answer.

✅ Publishing (PHP -> Broker) works

✅ Device Subscription (Broker -> Device

✅ Publishing the answer (Device -> Broker) works

But... the timeout is always reached even though the answer is sent to the correct topic about 2-3 sec. after the request. Do you have any ideas??

Here is my code:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpMqtt\Client\MqttClient;
use PhpMqtt\Client\ConnectionSettings;
use PhpMqtt\Client\Message;

$broker = 'test.mosquitto.org';
$port = 1883;

$username = '';
$password = ''; 
$mainTopic = '!!!testlab';
$ackTimeout = 30;

$testMessage = 'Broker Test';
$brokerStatus = sendText($broker, $port, $username, $password, $mainTopic, $testMessage, $ackTimeout);

if ($brokerStatus === 0) {
    echo "Broker OK, RPi OK\n";
} elseif ($brokerStatus === 1) {
    die("Broker offline\n");
} else {
    die("Broker OK, RPi Timeout\n");
}

function sendText($broker, $port, $username, $password, $mainTopic, $message, $ackTimeout)
{
    try {
        $client = new MqttClient($broker, $port, 'php-client');
        $settings = (new ConnectionSettings);

        if (!empty($username)) {
            $settings->setUsername($username);
        }

        if (!empty($password)) {
            $settings->setPassword($password);
        }

        $client->connect($settings);

        $messageId = uniqid();
        $subTopic = $mainTopic . '/' . $messageId;
        $acknowledgmentTopic = $subTopic . '/ack';

        $messageData = [
            'id' => $messageId,
            'message' => $message,
            'timestamp' => time(),
        ];
        $messagePayload = json_encode($messageData);

        $acknowledgment = null;

        $startTime = microtime(true);

        $client->subscribe($acknowledgmentTopic, function (Message $message) use ($acknowledgmentTopic, &$acknowledgment) {
            
            $acknowledgmentData = json_decode($message->getPayload(), true);

            if ($acknowledgmentData && isset($acknowledgmentData['code'])) {
                $acknowledgmentCode = $acknowledgmentData['code'];
                $acknowledgmentMessage = isset($acknowledgmentData['message']) ? $acknowledgmentData['message'] : '';

                if ($acknowledgmentCode == 0) {
                    $acknowledgment = 0;
                } else {
                    $acknowledgment = (int)$acknowledgmentCode;
                }
            }
        });

        $client->registerLoopEventHandler(function (MqttClient $client) use ($acknowledgmentTopic, &$acknowledgment, $ackTimeout, $startTime) {
            if ($acknowledgment !== null) {
                $client->interrupt();
            }

            $elapsedTime = microtime(true) - $startTime;

            if ($elapsedTime >= $ackTimeout) {
                $acknowledgment = 2;
                $client->interrupt();
            }
        });
        
        $client->publish($subTopic . '/text', $messagePayload);

        $client->loop();

        $client->disconnect();

        return $acknowledgment ?? 2;
    } catch (\Throwable $e) {
        if($debug){echo "Fehler: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";}
        return 1; // Verbindungsfehler zum Broker
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You publish, run the client loop once, then disconnect the client, the loop function needs to be run to both send the message and to handle any incoming messages for topics you have subscribed to...

Comment: @hardillb How could I keep the loop running?

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code. Maybe add a try-catch to your subscription callback and introduce logging in case parsing the acknowledgement fails (or something else goes wrong). The MQTT client is swallowing exceptions in callbacks to prevent a single callback from taking down all other callbacks.